# Why would my house be so humid even when the A/C is running?

Tags: hvac

I live in Florida which this year has been particularly hot and humid. However, a while back I noticed mold in my closet and a very musty smell in my living room.
Actually I even found mold growing on a wooden chair in my bedroom.

About 4 or 5 years ago I replace my central a/c with a hi efficiency SEER 18+.

Unable to locate any leaks which might be responsible I purchased a 70 pt dehumidifier which has run constantly.  when I first turned on the dehumidifier, I read that the  existing humidity was over 70%
Is this normal, or are their other factors at play?  My house is 1700 sf (with high ceilings and the a/c is 3 ton.

Comment: This is not normal.  Do you have a framed or stick built house?  Carpet or tile? What year was it built?

Comment: its a concrete block built in 1994.  floors or either title or wood, no carpet.

Comment: If you're healthy and reasonably fit, get up in the attic and see if you can find any disconnected ducts or signs of water leaks.  Of course, go early in the morning or after the sun goes down.

Answer (score 3):

A few theories as to what might be going on:

- You have bad ductwork with few returns. If that's the case, you're just not moving enough air to dehumidify every room.
- Your AC unit is oversized. And oversized AC unit will cool the air very fast and then shut off. The problem with that is if the AC unit is only running for short periods, it's not given enough time to properly dehumidify the air.
- You have massive air leaks in the house. Maybe as simple as an open door or window. Maybe more complex like no insulation or air barriers in the walls.
- You have a massive water leak in the house. Leaking foundation/crawlspace, leaking pluming in the wall, roof leak, etc.

A 1700sf isn't a huge house, so I have a hunch a 3 ton unit is simply too big for your particular house. On average, do you know how often the AC kicks on and for how long? Do you know if they did proper calculations on your house before sizing the unit?

Comment: 3 ton doesn't sound too big for a single story in Florida.  I have a 2040 sqft home with a 5 ton unit.  Works fine.

Comment: @Edwin depends entirely on the house. A super insulated home, 3  tons might be double what's needed. A poorly insulated house with 8' south facing window, 3 tons might not nearly be enough.

Comment: @Cat I would suspect to that this may be a central return type system. Can you confirm that you have either 1 cold air return, or one in each room?

Comment: Plus one for oversized. The title should probably read: why is it like this while it's set to 'on', instead of while 'running'.